# Detect separate touches on different SpriteKit nodes?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making a SpriteKit game where in order to begin the game, you need to hold two separate spots (SKShapeNodes) for 3 seconds. If you let go either finger or move either finger off a node, the game will not start. I have it working fine with 1 spot, but when I try to do 2 spots, I'm stuck. What is the simplest way to detect the 2 correct touches on the correct nodes?

This doesn't seem like a very uncommon situation, so if anyone knows the best way to handle this, I would appreciate the help.

Swift preferred, also.

Answer (score 0):

Set multipleTouchEnabled to YES and use the `touchesForView:` method.

You can get more specific information on multi touch from the [Apple Docs Multitouch Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9).

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to have all touches when users provides any actions and operate them at the same time.

So, add 3 handlers to your Scene class:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    checkTouches((event?.allTouches())!)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    checkTouches((event?.allTouches())!)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    checkTouches((event?.allTouches())!)
}
```

In the checkTouches function you will see all touches with updated properties (like positions etc).

Simple example:

```
func checkTouches(touches: Set<UITouch>) {
    // iterate over all touches
    for t in touches {
        let touch = t as UITouch
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if... <-- YOUR CODE HERE TO CHECK NODE NAME AND TOUCHED TIME
    }
}
```

Using this approach you will be able to handle any changes simultaniously.
E.g. user may touch on your node, then move finger outside it and then move bach to this node.

Enjoy!